Using `kotlinx.datetime.Instant` in JDBC causes the timestamp to drift
Converting between Instant and Timestamp in JDBC is causing the time to drift by the difference between the system timezone and UTC.

When setting an Instant to a TIMESTAMP field in JDBC, do this to prevent the time from drifting by the difference between your system timezone and UTC.
preparedStatement.setTimestamp(
                    place,
                    Timestamp.valueOf(
                        LocalDateTime.ofInstant(
                            param.toJavaInstant(),
                            ZoneId.of(Calendar.getInstance().timeZone.id)
                        )
                    )
                )

No care needs to be taken when retrieving the TIMESTAMP because it comes with a TZ that the Instant accounts for.
